# Interact with cell

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I want to change background and on text color of cell on tap, and keep active status this for cell until other cell is taped. This active status will lose. I use Swift 3 and this is my source :

```
let selectedView = UIView()
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
   let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
   selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
   cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

   return true
}
```

This code worked but it not remove active status

Comment: `until other cell is taped` *…tapped*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: Is there any reason you use a separate view instead of just using `cell?.backgroundColor`?

2nd: You shouldn't use force unwrap. Either use `?` or use optional binding

3rd: You probably should rather use `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` for this, since `tableView(_:shouldHighlightRowAt:)` is more for the system hilight.

4th: To solve your problem, you should keep a pointer around to the cell that you currently hilight. So when you call `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` again first think you can do is reset the old cell's hilight.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are describing, setting the cell's appearance in should be fine, it will take immediate effect when you start the tap (not simply when you let go).

At this point, with a bare-bones table (no other custom code), the cell is **selected**.

NOTE: Re-tapping the same cell will keep it selected, not de-select... (that's another piece of code).

If you tap on another row, that cell becomes selected, and by default, the other cell becomes unselected. But your code's changes should still take effect.

If you put log lines into all the relevant functions, you would see:

I used -> `print (#function, "indexPath:", indexPath)`

So click on the second cell, it says selected, then click on the first cell, and it becomes the only selected cell ->

```
tableView(_:shouldHighlightRowAt:) [0, 0] -> (returns true by default)
tableView(_:didHighlightRowAt:) [0, 0] -> cell becomes highlighted
tableView(_:didUnhighlightRowAt:) [0, 0] -> (no visual change)
tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:) [0, 0] -> cell becomes selected (looks same as highlighted)
tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:) [0, 1] -> the *other* cell->unselected
tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) [0, 0]
```

So, I would consider un-doing the changes there, esp. if you have a pretty stock tableview.

NOTE: I had a minor problem with my `willDeselectRowAt` method when I wrote this, lets just assume happened as well...